# How to prevent route changing?

Tags: angularjs

I have a service in which inside I bind a click event:

```
$('button').click(function() {
alert('Clicked');
return false;
});
```

The issue is when I do not start at the default "/" route (i.e. "/testroute"), then that same button when clicked, causes the page url to go to "/" and not fire my event at all. When I click on it again after the route changes to "/", the event triggers as normal. How do I make it such that if I were to start at /testroute (even though it has the same view, different controller, but shares the same service, the alert will fire?

Comment: Wheres the angularjs? Looks like jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use locationChangeStart. Also read the link Andrey posted.

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [these](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location#Events) events to prevent route changing.